# How to applying THREE.EdgesGeometry in a object loaded with THREE.OBJLoader?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I try several times to implement the edges in a model loader with the OBJLoader but can't do it.

```
Mloader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
            Mloader.setPath( dir );
            Mloader.load( mtl_dir, function ( materials ) {
                materials.preload();
                OLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                OLoader.setMaterials( materials );
                OLoader.setPath( dir );
                OLoader.load( name_file, function ( object ) {
                    object.scale.set( scale, scale, scale );
                    scene.add( object );
                    var edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( object, 11 );
                    var line = new THREE.LineSegments( edges, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( {color: 0x111111 } ) );
                    line.scale.set( scale, scale, scale );
                    scene.add( line )
                } );
            } );
```

The model load fine, but the edges don't. 
When the model is loader with the STLloader the edges of the geometry render fine, but i need to do it with .obs files.

```
var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
loader.load(dir, function (geometry) {

material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xAAAAAA,
    specular: 0x111111,
    shininess: 200
});
var edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(geometry, 11);

var line = new THREE.LineSegments(edges, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0x111111}));   
line.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);

scene.add(line)

});
```

[STL vs OBJ Loader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni8ig.png)

Comment: You must pass a `geometry` to the `EdgesGeometry` constructor. What is `object`?

Comment: Yes i do it `var edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( object, 11 );` but it doesn't work. The `object` i supost to be a `BufferGeometry` or a `Geometry`.

Comment: And what type is `object` in your case?

Comment: `object` it's created when the loader run, `OBJloader.load( name_file, function ( object ) { ...`, so the type it's defined according to the OBJloader.js

Comment: Right. It is probably an `Object3D` or `Group` with children. Use the debugger to determine what it is in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, yes it a group. The code with the solution:

```
Mloader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
            Mloader.setPath( dir );
            Mloader.load( mtl_dir, function ( materials ) {
                materials.preload();
                OLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                OLoader.setMaterials( materials );
                OLoader.setPath( dir );
                OLoader.load( name_file, function ( object ) {
                    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                            child.castShadow = true;
                            edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( child.geometry,11);
                            line = new THREE.LineSegments( edges, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( {
                            color: 0x111111
                        } ) );
                            line.scale.set( scale, scale, scale );
                            line.position.set( 0, 0.7, 0 );
                            scene.add( line );
                        }
                    } );

                        object.scale.set( scale, scale, scale );
                        object.position.set( 0, 0.7, 0 );
                        scene.add( object );
                    } );
            } );
```